# multiple mpu9250 using tca9548a with esp32

Tags: esp32, mpu6050, multiplexer

I'm using ESP32 and 1 sensor mpu9250(only for test) with tca9548a, connections are:

TCA <-> ESP

VIN - VCC

GND - GND

SDA - GPIO21

SCL - GPIO22

TCA <-> MPU

SD2 - SDA

SC2 - SCL

VIN - VIN

GND - GND

And my code here:

```
#include <SparkFunMPU9250-DMP.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define TCAADDR 0x70
void tcaselect(uint8_t i) {
  if (i > 7) return;
 
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCAADDR);
  Wire.write(1 << i);
  Wire.endTransmission();  
}

MPU9250_DMP imu;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
  tcaselect(2);
  if (imu.begin() != INV_SUCCESS)
  {
    while (1)
    {
      Serial.println("Unable to communicate with MPU-9250");
      Serial.println("Check connections, and try again.");
      Serial.println();
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
  
  imu.dmpBegin(DMP_FEATURE_6X_LP_QUAT | // Enable 6-axis quat
               DMP_FEATURE_GYRO_CAL, // Use gyro calibration
              10); // Set DMP FIFO rate to 10 Hz
              delay(10000);
}

void loop() 
{
  tcaselect(2);
    imu.dmpUpdateFifo();
  float q0 = imu.calcQuat(imu.qw);
  float q1 = imu.calcQuat(imu.qx);
  float q2 = imu.calcQuat(imu.qy);
  float q3 = imu.calcQuat(imu.qz);
  Serial.println("Q: " + String(q0, 4) + ", " +
                    String(q1, 4) + ", " + String(q2, 4) + 
                    ", " + String(q3, 4));delay(10);
}
```

I need to get quaternions from the MPU sensor but I'm only getting zeros on the output.

[image]

Library that I used: https://github.com/rupin/SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library

What could be wrong, my connection or library?

Comment: did you read the answer to this question? https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/70834/multiple-mpu9250-synced

Comment: You could try adapting the I2C Scanner sketch to use the TCA9548a like you do. Then you can check if the MPU is really visible on the bus. I would think, that the Arduino cannot reach the MPUn thus giving only zeros

Comment: @Juraj yes, I will try this method later. But now I'd like to figure out why my method doesn't work

Comment: @Juraj It works, thanks!

Comment: @chrisl It`s true, TCA scanner cannot find any addresses of MPU9250. Seems like clock stretching(idk). But now I use method of changing address of MPU that i use in 1 tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that I just removed the tca9548a from the circuit. Then I connected each AD0 pin to the corresponding GPIO ESP32 pins to turn on the sensor, I send a low signal to it, and a high signal to all the others. Thus, the library only works with a sensor whose address is 0x68.

There is example function from my sketch:

```
#include <SparkFunMPU9250-DMP.h>

/*INIT SENSORS*/
MPU9250_DMP imu;
MPU9250_DMP imu1;
const int sensor1 = 18;
const int sensor2 = 19;

String IMU_1Update(){
  String res;
    digitalWrite(sensor1, LOW); // 1st sensor enable - 0x68
    digitalWrite(sensor2, HIGH); // 2nd sensor disable - 0x69
  if ( imu1.fifoAvailable() ){
    if ( imu1.dmpUpdateFifo() == INV_SUCCESS){
      float q0 = imu1.calcQuat(imu1.qw);
      float q1 = imu1.calcQuat(imu1.qx);
      float q2 = imu1.calcQuat(imu1.qy);
      float q3 = imu1.calcQuat(imu1.qz);
      Serial.print("G1|");
      Serial.print(q0);
      Serial.print("|");
      Serial.print(q1);
      Serial.print("|");
      Serial.print(q2);
      Serial.print("|");
      Serial.print(q3);
      Serial.println("|");
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```